# Is there proof that pulsars beam like a lighthouse?

Tags: astrophysics

Shortly after pulsars were discovered in the late 1960s, Scientific American had an article about the new discovery. I believe the author of the article was not sure whether pulsars were beaming radiation like a lighthouse or pulsating out radiation equally in all directions. Currently, all the scientific literature I have read states unequivocally that pulsars beam like a lighthouse. Was this ever proven experimentally? ... for example, by checking for max amplitude delay consistent with beam rotation at widely spaced terrestrial antennas?

Comment: Your example is a good one, good enough that it's being used as the basis for pulsar-based navigational systems: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-017-0459-0